# Object Defined error! Am i missing something?

Tags: vba, object

I am relatively new to vba but i've been stuck on this code for hours. Unable to figure out whats wrong with it. I get a debugging error at 
" If Cells(Counter, 1).Value <> Empty Then Flag = False"

It says Application defined or object defined error. I don't see what the problem lies in though. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Macro1()



ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Workbooks("Cerebus.xlsm").Sheets("Tree").Activate
N = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value
Flag = True
Counter = 11

# Counter loops

Do While (Flag = True)
Counter = Counter + 1
If Cells(Counter, 1).Value <> Empty Then Flag = False
Loop

# adjusting for white space
For i = 10 To (Counter - 11) + Counter + 1
For j = 1 To (Counter - 11) / 2 + 1
Cells (i,j).Select
Selection.Clear
Next
Next

For i = 0 To N
Cells(10, N + 1).Value = N
Cells(11 + i * 4, N + 1).Value = 5
Cells(11 + i * 4, N + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Cells(11 + i * 4 + 1, N + 1).Value = 5
Cells(11 + i * 4 + 1, N + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
Next

For j = 1 To N
For i = 0 To N - j
Cells(10, N - j + 1).Value = N - j
Cells(11 + 2 * j + i * 4, N - j + 1).Value = 6
Cells(11 + 2 * j + i * 4, N - j + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Cells(11 + 2 * j + i * 4 + 1, N - j + 1).Value = 6
Cells(11 + 2 * j + i * 4 + 1, N - j + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: First thing, I suggest you to enable the "Require Variable Declaration" in "Tools/Options".  And maybe you can check the value of `Counter`, does it throw error in first loop?

Comment: 1st line ... which sheet are you unprotecting?  ... use fully qualified object names like `N = Workbooks("Cerebus.xlsm").Sheets("Tree").Cells(3, 2).Value` and `Workbooks("Cerebus.xlsm").Sheets("Tree").Cells (i,j).Clear` ... you can define objects if you want to simplify the code ... `Dim sh As Worksheet` and `Set sh = Workbooks("Cerebus.xlsm").Sheets("Tree")` then `N = sh.Cells(3, 2).Value` and so on

Comment: you can also change the value of multiple cells `Workbooks("Cerebus.xlsm").Sheets("Tree").Range("a1:d10").Clear` same with changing color and other attributes

Comment: Thanks, thats a very good suggestion. let me try it!
if u type that as an answer i;ll upvote u

Answer (score 2):

If the error is **1004** and occurs at

> ```
> If Cells(Counter, 1).Value <> Empty Then Flag = False
> ```

the only reason I can imagine is that the Counter went beyond the maximum allowed `Rows.Count` (i.e. 1048576). That would mean you don't have any non-empty cells below row `11` in your sheet and hence `Flag` was never reset to `False`.

It is quite possible that the `ActiveSheet` isn't the one you actually think it is. Best solution is to drop the use of `ActiveSheet` and replace it by an **explicit** worksheet.